# Thrust by turbo fan jet engine

Tags: mechanical-engineering, chemical-engineering, aerospace-engineering, process-engineering, power-engineering

How much thrust can I produce with a turbofan jet engine without injection of fuel and with just compression of air, which will be heated by convection if initial temperature of air of 20 <sup>o</sup>C and its temperature after compression is 1400 <sup>o</sup>C, which is then diffused through nozzle of the jet.

I want to produce approximately 6.8 kN of thrust.

Comment: You don't get anything out with the compressor. You have an electric or diesel motor turning a ducted fan and turning a compressor. If you don't need the compressed air, get rid of the compressor and just turn the fan. A jet engine burns fuel just like a diesel. No fuel, no power. Some of the heat of compression will always be lost to the environment and not recoverable, so it is always lossy without fuel burn.

Comment: That wasn't my downvote, btw.

Comment: What if i power compressor using a motor or some other source, and compress air and heat it using some source, then alow it to expend while keeping the cross section area content, and let ut flow out of nozzle,

Comment: I want compressor to suck and compress air, then i want to expand air by heating it using some source but not fuel, its discharge will be same but volume will be increased, so velocity of air coming out of jet will be more, i think thrust is proportional to velocity of air coming out of jet, so there will be some thrust,

Comment: I am compressing air for reducing cross section area of duct through which it is flowing and to increase its temperature, then i have some source of heat. In the next part or section of jet AKA combustion chamber., if temperature in the combustion chamber is 1400 degree C, and them i have a diffuser or nozzle to diffuse air out at greater velocity, volume will increase due to temperature, and its discharge must be constant so velocity must be high, now tell me how much thrust roughly it can produce. I just want 6.8 KN of thrust. If temperature raise if 1380 degree C, and what will be minimum c

Comment: What will be minimum cross section area required to produce 6.8KN of thrust.

Comment: You need to model the thermodynamic cycle for your proposed machine. We can't guess exactly how you think it is supposed to work.

Comment: Start with a book such as: https://www.amazon.com/Engineering-Thermodynamics-S-I-Units-Transfer-1967-09-03/dp/B01FKTAP4Q/ref=sr_1_fkmr2_2?keywords=mass+transfer+rogers+%26+mayhew&qid=1582875270&sr=8-2-fkmr2

Answer (score 0):

There's at least 10 parameters you need to know before you could calculate thrust.  What is your bypass ratio?  What is the mass flow?  What is the ambient temperature and pressure?  What is the forward velocity?  what is the compression ratio?  etc, etc, etc.  You really need either a textbook on jet engine performance, or take a class.  NASA has a very crude simulator that might get you started https://www.grc.nasa.gov/WWW/K-12/airplane/ngnsim.html

Comment: Completely agree on this, that i need to have several parameters, but question is, how can i calculate these para meters, is there any design book which can make it little easier, or can i connect to you? For some help, i know may parameter already. Ill tell you all condition, may be you can help?

Comment: Drop your email. You are intrested.

Comment: To be clear, are you asking to hire me as a consultant, or are you looking for free help by email? Free help is going to be pretty much limited to the above. Go find a textbook or take a class. But if you are looking to hire a consultant then by all means let's talk

Comment: I am looking for hiring a consultant, lets talk. How can we connect

Comment: @MarshallJaySoni I have added my e-mail address to my profile.  Please contact me there and we can discuss.